# What are all the previous Oracle text revisions for Time Vault?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

On Gatherer, I can see the original wording for [Time Vault](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Time%20Vault):

> Tap to gain an additional turn after the current one. Time Vault doesn't untap normally during untap phase; to untap it, you must skip a turn. Time Vault begins tapped.

And I can see the most recent errata:

> Time Vault enters the battlefield tapped.
> Time Vault doesn't untap during your untap step.
> If you would begin your turn while Time Vault is tapped, you may skip that turn instead. If you do, untap Time Vault.
> Tap: Take an extra turn after this one.

Using Google, I was able to find a [few more](http://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/latest-developments/power-level-errata-b-gone-2006-07-14) [revisions](http://www.starcitygames.com/magic/vintage/11812_Deus_Ex_Errata_Debating_the_Changes_to_Time_Vault.html):

> Time Vault comes into play tapped.
> Time Vault doesn't untap during your untap step.
> Skip your next turn: Untap Time Vault and put a time counter on it.
> T, Remove all time counters from Time Vault: Take an extra turn after this one. Play this ability if only there's a time counter on Time Vault.

> Time Vault comes into play tapped.
> Time Vault doesn't untap during your untap step.
> At the beginning of your upkeep you may untap Time Vault. If you do, put a time counter on it and you skip your next turn.
> T, Remove all time counters from Time Vault: Take an extra turn after this one. Play this ability only if there's a time counter on Time Vault.

> Time Vault comes into play tapped.
> If Time Vault would become untapped, instead choose one -- untap Time Vault and you skip your next turn; or Time Vault remains tapped.
> T: Take an extra turn after this one.

... But are there any more versions? For the sake of historical curiosity, I'm interested in seeing every revision listed in one place.

Answer (score 4):

According to [MtG Goldfish](http://www.mtggoldfish.com/articles/evolution-of-magic-the-roller-coaster-called-time-vault) the different erratas of Time Vault are as follows.

1993, the original printing:

> Tap to gain an additional turn after the current one. Time Vault doesn't untap normally during untap phase; to untap it, you must skip a turn. Time Vault begins tapped.

1996, made some power level errata to make it go from broken to useless:

> Does not untap as normal. If Time Vault is tapped and does not have a time counter, you may skip your turn to untap Time Vault and put a time counter on it. {tap}: Remove the time counter from Time Vault to take an additional turn immediately before the next normal turn.

1998 & 2004, edited the template to match current rules. (this is the 2004 text):

> Time Vault comes into play tapped.
> Time Vault doesn't untap during your untap step.
> Skip your next turn: Untap time vault and put a time counter on it.
> {T}, Remove all time counters from Time Vault: Take an extra turn after this one. Play this ability if only there's a time counter on Time Vault.

March 2006, to stop an unintended combo with [Flame Fusillade](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Flame%20Fusillade) abusing unlimited untaps:

> Time Vault comes into play tapped.
> Time Vault doesn't untap during your untap step.
> At the beginning of your upkeep you may untap Time Vault. If you do put a time counter on it and you skip your next turn.
> {T} Remove all time counters from Time Vault: Take an extra turn after this one. Play this ability only if there's a time counter on Time Vault.

July 2006, as far as I can tell there isn't a reason for this eratta (other than bad [Mizzium Transreliquat](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mizzium%20Transreliquat) combos):

> Time Vault comes into play tapped.
> If Time Vault would become untapped, instead choose one -- untap Time Vault and you skip your next turn or Time Vault remains tapped.
> {T}: Take an extra turn after this one.

2008, Wizards finally decides to remove all power level errata and returns Time Vault to its original functionality just with an updated template:

> Time Vault enters the Battlefield tapped.
> Time Vault doesn't untap during your untap step.
> If you would begin your turn while Time Vault is tapped, you may skip that turn instead. If you do, untap Time Vault.
> {T}: Take an extra turn after this one.

Comment: That article is a nice find, +1. I just wish the author could have found the 1998 text! I know he says that it was a small change "to keep it up to date with the latest templating", so there probably wasn't a functional difference, but I'm still curious as to what it was.